# Add custom wizards to new menu in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I'm working on a plugin and I developed a custom wizard for creating new type of project in Eclipse Luna. By default it's added in other category. My question is how to add it to File -> New menu, like on the picture, so users can access it easily? I would like it to be positioned above Java Project.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 'new wizard shortcut'. You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to do this for a particular perspective. Use the `newWizardShortcut` element.

For example:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective"> 
        <newWizardShortcut id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewProjectCreationWizard"/> 
    </perspectiveExtension> 
</extension>
```

Adds a wizard to the resources perspective.

Only wizards marked as Project wizard are put in the top section.

You may need to do a 'Perspective > Reset Perspective' to get Eclipse to find the new extension.

Comment: It definitely works. You may need to do a 'Perspective > Reset Perspective' to get Eclipse to find your new extension.